# How can I resolve this CORS error when trying to access data from The Movie Database Api?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-redux, cors

**Thank You In Advance**

I get there's a lot here and it definitely could be overwhelming to try to solve this. I just wanna say I appreciate any one that takes the time to try to solve my mess. This is the first project that I've really gone the distance with and it sucks to run into something stubborn like this LOL. That's what we sign up for. I'll still keep working to solve the issue on my own. Thanks again!

**Live Error Example**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L4HSNPLUmm5I5pVk1DRMipmt6mRZ8gtR/view

**Live Working Example**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TVMNKTSiHqz0rbg1zS_g743FqpMxCEHE/view

**Issue**

So There are 3 steps that are within this whole issue. On the 3rd step is where I run into my issue.

**First step**, when the app loads, it will render a sign in component page that will ask for user credentials. I will then sign in with valid credentials. Once I hit submit, it will hit one of my express routes in the back-end that has to do with user authentication. What this route will do is check my MongoDB to see if this user already exists, then generate a token from "jsonwebtoken" npm package and will send that token back as a response. In the front end, I then will have functionality that will set that token in local storage. If there is a present token in local storage, I will then load user credentials (token, username, etc.) and reroute to the /home component.

**Second Step**, once the home component renders/mounts, I will then make another request to The Movie Database Api, from the front end and render a list of popular movies displaying their movie banners.
The Data is returned just fine.

**Third step** and **issue**, when I click on one of the popular movies, I make another request from the front-end to The Movie Database Api that passes the popular movie's Id as a paramater and get back the movie details as a response. Simultaneously, I will route to a movieDetails component. The issue is, I don't actually get back the data. Instead, I get back the CORS error.

**CORS Error**

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/419704?api_key=XXXXXX&append_to_response=credits' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field **x-auth-token** is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

**Other Console Errors**

GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key=XXXXXX net::ERR_FAILED

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)

**setAuthToken() Section**

Also, I have a utilities function that is called setAuthToken, which involves 'x-auth-token' shown above in the CORS error.
This pretty much just sets the x-auth-token header to a present token for every axios request, only if there is a token present.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const setAuthToken = (token) => {
    if(token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token'] = token;
        console.log(axios.defaults.headers.common)
    }else {
        delete axios.defaults.headers.common['x-auth-token']
    }
}

export default setAuthToken;
```

I am using this function twice in App.js.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
// Components
import Landing from "./pages/landing/landing.component";
import Home from "./pages/home/home.component";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/navbar.component";
import MovieDetails from "./pages/movie-details/movie-details.component";
import Search from "./pages/search/search.component";
import Sidebar from "./components/sidebar/sidebar.component";
import SidebarDesktop from "./components/sidebar-desktop/sidebar-desktop.component";
import SignInAndSignUp from "./pages/sign-in-and-sign-up/sign-in-and-sign-up.component";
import Thread from "./pages/thread/thread.component";
import SignUp from "./pages/sign-up/sign-up.component";

// Redux
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getPopular } from "./redux/movies/movies.actions";
import { loadUser } from "./redux/auth/auth.actions";
import setAuthToken from "./utils/setAuthToken";

if (localStorage.token) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
}

const App = ({ getPopular, loadUser }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getPopular();
    console.log("Rendered");
    loadUser();
  }, []);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
        <Route exact path="/movie-details/:slug" component={MovieDetails} />
        <Route exact path="/search/:title" component={Search} />
        <Route exact path="/sign-in-and-sign-up" component={SignInAndSignUp} />
      </Switch>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default connect(null, { getPopular, loadUser })(App);
```

First use is within an if statement that invokes **setAuthToken** directly, based off if there is a token in local storage.

Second use is within a useEffect function that fires an action called **loadUser**.

**loadUser** hits a back-end auth GET route that first hits a middleware function which checks to see if the 'x-auth-token' header has a token. Middleware is done. Then, if there is a token present within the request header, it will get this users id that was first generated upon sign in and query MongoDB for this users info by id (username, avatar, etc.).

**loadUser()**

```
export const loadUser = () => async dispatch => {
    if(localStorage.token) {
        setAuthToken(localStorage.token)
    }

    try {
        const res = await axios.get('/api/auth');
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED,
            payload: res.data
        })
        console.log(res.data)
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: AUTH_ERROR
        })
    }
}
```

**Middleware to -  GET auth route**

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('config');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.header('x-auth-token');
    
    if(!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: 'No token, authorization denied' })
    }
 

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'));
        console.log('Decoded', decoded)

        req.user = decoded.user;
        console.log('Req User', req.user)
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(401).json({ message: 'Token is not valid' })
    }
}
```

**GET auth route**

```
// @route    GET api/auth
// @desc     Get user by token
// @access   Private
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
    res.json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

At this point, the app now has the currently authenticated user's info.

**Redux Actions**

This is where I run into the CORS error when trying to access a specific movie's details.

```
export const getMovieById = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  let API_KEY = "XXXXXXX";
  let baseURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/";

  try {
    axios
      .get(
        `${baseURL}movie/${id}?api_key=${API_KEY}&append_to_response=credits`
      )

      .then((res) => {
        // Target Cast List and Enable Profile Image
        res.data.credits.cast.map((profile) => {
          profile.profile_image = `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${profile.profile_path}`;
        });
        res.data.credits.cast.map((profile) => {
          if (
            profile.profile_image === "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/originalnull"
          ) {
            profile.notFoundIcon = "fas fa-user fa-3x";
          }
        });

        // Target Crew List and Enable Profile Image
        res.data.credits.crew.map((profile) => {
          profile.profile_image = `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${profile.profile_path}`;
        });
        res.data.credits.crew.map((profile) => {
          if (
            profile.profile_image === "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/originalnull"
          ) {
            profile.notFoundIcon = "fas fa-user fa-3x";
          }
        });

        const movie = {
          ...res.data,
          customImageURL: `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${res.data.poster_path}`,
          customBanner: `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${res.data.backdrop_path}`,
        };

        dispatch({
          type: GET_MOVIE_DETAILS,
          payload: movie,
        });
      });
  } catch (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Server Error");
    console.error("Server Error");
  }
};
```

**Final Thoughts**

So I have two servers running, which are react and express. I am using the npm package "concurrently" to run both servers at once. I do have the correct code in the package.json that can make this happen. Also, I am running a proxy through my react client package.json that connects to my back-end.

**Here's the kicker**

When I only start up my react server and not both, my app runs fine and I am not running into the CORS error upon clicking a popular movie to retrieve the movie data. But when I run both servers, I get the CORS error upon clicking one of the popular movies.

**Live Error Example**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L4HSNPLUmm5I5pVk1DRMipmt6mRZ8gtR/view

**Live Working Example**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TVMNKTSiHqz0rbg1zS_g743FqpMxCEHE/view

Comment: So what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score -1):

require the cors in your main server file i think in your case is app.js
install cors using

```
npm install cors
```

than require it in app.js file

```
let cors = require('cors');
```

after this

```
app.use(cors());
```

this will accept all request from client side

Answer (score -1):

Just curious if you are using the 'cors' package on the Movie API Server?

The most likely reason why you are experiencing this issue is because of a preflight check between your React Application and The Movie Database API. Prior to any communication the browser inquires with the server whether the server is configured to accept a request from a different origin.

To resolve the "CORS" issue, you would need to allow cross origins, by installing the following package. Please make sure you are in the Movie Database API project.

```
npm install cors
```

After installing the package, you would need to configure your Movie Database API middleware and add the following to the express application.

First import the package dependency:

```
const cors = require('cors');
```

Assuming the initialization of your express app is stored in a variable called "app":

```
app.use(cors())
```

If you are looking for more information on the "cors" package, see the link below. If the link expires, you can do a quick web search for "express cors".

[Here is how you can set it up for your API Server, if it is not already.](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)